# Where to place database files in Visual Studio

Tags: database, visual-studio, mdf

If this question has been asked before please point me in the right direction.

I am working with an MDF file which I attach to localdb in Visual Studio.
However, when I run my application it is copied to the Debug folder (I know this is because the "Copy always" option is set)

This works fine because my connection string is:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Invoicing.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

which means my application will look for the database in the Debug folder.

My question is, where should I place the database file because :
1. The file I am attaching to localdb is under the projects folder
2. Meanwhile, my application looks for the database file in the debug folder

I would appreciate any guidelines

Answer (score 0):

I found this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx

I guess I will have to attach the one in the bin folder and choose the option to copy if newer

EDIT:
I have done the above and in addition I have created two connections, one for the MDF in the projects folder and the other to view data in the database in the bin folder